# how to say "If the formula in this named range returns an error, then the value is one, else zero" in Excel

Tags: excel

Hi guys i would like to ask a very simple question,how to say  "If the formula in this named range returns an error, then the value is one, else zero" in Excel?
I was thinking like "IF (A1:A200 Returns an Error, 1, 0).

I attach a screenshot so you guys could see what i am trying to do, the cells in red are the ones that contains error.

[image]

Thanks guys, your help would be very appreciated.

Comment: That screenshot doesn't appear to have any obvious relationship to your problem. What are you actually trying to do, and why? Also, consider a smaller screenshot with larger, legible font size. That is literally impossible to read the one you have already posted.

Comment: See here: http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/count-errors.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` and `ISERR` (or `ISERROR`, see note below on the difference between these) functions. This will count the number of errors in the range:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISERR(A1:A200))
```

[image]

Then, wrap it in an `IF`, like:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISERR(A1:A200))>0,1,0)
```

[image]

[HERE](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-cells-that-contain-errors) is a good explanation of how the functions work.

**NOTE**: `ISERR` counts all errors except `#N/A`. If you want to also count `#N/A`, use the `ISERROR` function instead of `ISERR`.

Comment: it may be worth specifically including the note in the link:  Note: ISERR counts all errors except #N/A. If you want to also count #N/A, use the ISERROR function instead of ISERR.

Comment: @sous2817 noted & revised!

Comment: Perfect!  I'm not sure what the etiquette is on editing perfectly good answers with a bit more detail, so thought I'd leave it as a comment.

Comment: @sous2817 It wouldn't have bothered me, and actually I've made similar edits to other answers in the past. I think as long as you're *improving* the answer I don't think most people would be bothered by it.

Comment: ah, good to know. I'm a long time lurker, short time contributor so trying to learn the ropes a bit w/o ending up on Meta :).